# How can I use this stack trace to tell what is causing my controller's action to break?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, renderaction

In my ASP.NET MVC app, I have a view that's calling `Html.Action("MyAction", this.Model)` - I have a similar scenario in a different controller and it works fine, but in this case, it breaks. I set a breakpoint on the first line of `MyAction`, but it's not breaking, so the error must occur before that point in the code.

```
System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'. ---&gt; System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---&gt; System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'. ---&gt; System.Web.HttpException: Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at Cobalt.Website.Platform.Web.Controllers.Controller.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) in D:\data\Website\App\Website\Controllers\Controller.cs:line 920
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__4()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8`1.&lt;BeginSynchronous&gt;b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassa.&lt;EndProcessRequest&gt;b__9()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;Wrap&gt;b__3()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, Object routeValues)
   at ASP.search_views_searchresults_aspx.__RenderContent7(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in d:\data\Website\App\Website\Search\Views\SearchResults.aspx:line 39
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at ASP.views_shared_masters_cobaltpage_master.__Rendercoid_website_pageContent(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in d:\data\Website\App\Website\Views\Shared\Masters\CobaltPage.master:line 50
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at ASP.views_shared_masters_cobaltstatic_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in d:\data\Website\App\Website\Views\Shared\Masters\CobaltStatic.master:line 78
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.search_views_searchresults_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4bd59adb\8512bc8c\App_Web_creqrbqh.4.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;ProcessRequest&gt;b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;Wrap&gt;b__3()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.RenderViewPage(ViewContext context, ViewPage page)
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass14.&lt;InvokeActionResultWithFilters&gt;b__11()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass14.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass16.&lt;InvokeActionResultWithFilters&gt;b__13()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)--> </div>
```

How can I get from this stack trace to figuring out the code in my application that causes the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular problem is:

> System.Web.HttpException: Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.
>      at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
>      at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
>      at Cobalt.Website.Platform.Web.Controllers.Controller.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) in D:\data\Website\App\Website\Controllers\Controller.cs:line 920

Your exception handler is trying to set the response status code after the server has started outputting page content. You should try/catch the StatusCode set I guess, and put a breakpoint in the OnException code to see what the real exception is, although it appears to be from

> d:\data\Website\App\Website\Search\Views\SearchResults.aspx:line 39

Incidentally `Html.Action` generates the URL that triggers a particular action, and doesn't call the action itself. Did you mean [Html.RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703541.aspx)? I'm not sure passing the model in is correct, though - it's unlikely to have the route values as-is?

Comment: That line of code is just `Html.Action("MyAction", this.Model)`. That code works fine in other views but blows up in this one.

Comment: OK, fair enough. You realise that you're calling the [Action(actionName, routeValues)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423.aspx) overload and so it's trying to parse the model for route value parameters to assemble into the action URL? In which case there might a problem doing that for the model object for this specific page.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I didn't think there would be a URL associated with this action because it's a `ChildActionOnly` action... And I don't believe that there are routing values associated with the model in the other case where I have this working. But I'll check it out.

Comment: In that case you should either disable your OnException temporarily, or fix up the SetStatusCode to not trigger for failed RenderActions, or put a breakpoint on the Html.Action line and turn on Ctrl-Alt-E to catch where the exception is thrown so you can see what's really going wrong. If that doesn't help, also turn on step-into-framework-code in Tools, Option, Debug so you can see what's actaully going wrong in the MVC code.

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of the ability to step into framework code, that will definitely come in handy. I appreciate the tips.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get rid of this by returning a view() in the action other than retrun RedirectToAction("SomeAction");